# Clamav - OnAccessMountPath & OnAccessPrevention

Tags: clamav

I would like to watch entire file system. In clamav config file system I have set

```
OnAccessMountPath /
```

However I would like to have blocking mode. According to [documentation](https://www.clamav.net/documents/on-access-scanning), it is not possible to use command OnAccessMountPath with OnAccessPrevention, which I need for blocking mode. I didn't find any information about combination watching entire file system and blocking mode. Could someone help me, if there is any way, how to block malicious file and also watching entire file system by clamav?

Comment: I guess you could run two clamonacc services with two different configurations. But this will use more ressources of course :(